# Firebase: Stoping it from entering Firebase auth service, when the back button is pressed on specific view

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-authentication

Using firebase to create user sign-in as follow,

> **a)** Sign-up view -> **b)** Email view -> **c)** userName view

And have two button namely `back` and `next`, all of this can be seen below,

[image: ImageToSee]

Problem occurs when `view b` has previously visited `view c` and upon clicking `back button` on `view b`, Firebase falsely goes into user auth function (checked using breakpoints),

**Supporting code for `back button`,**

```
(IBAction)backButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    if(page==0)
    {

        UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Signup" message:@"Are you sure you want to quit signup?" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Yes" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action)
                             {
                                 [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                                 //BUTTON OK CLICK EVENT
                             }];
        UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:nil];
        [alert addAction:cancel];
        [alert addAction:ok];
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
else
{

    [self moveToPreviousStep];
}
    if (page==3){
        self.skipButton.hidden=YES;
    }
}
```

**Supporting code for `next button with Firebase specific code`,**

```
[ARSLineProgress showWithPresentCompetionBlock:^{


               [[FIRAuth auth] fetchProvidersForEmail:self.signUpEmail.text completion:^(NSArray<NSString *> * _Nullable providers, NSError * _Nullable error) {

                    [ARSLineProgress hideWithCompletionBlock:^{
                   if([providers count]==0)
                   {
                       NSLog(@"email is valid for signup");
                       signingUpFromEmail = TRUE;


                        [self moveToNextStep];
                   }
```

**What should happen,**

Upon clicking the `back button` in `view b` it should go into view a without getting into Firebase auth function, *(maybe it's a pending thread for firebase that needs to purged or it can be handled programatically)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there were two actions assigned to the `back` button i.e the `MoveNextPage` and `MoveBackPage` in storyboard (*rookie mistake as the next button was copied and pasted to back button position in storyboard)*, so the **removal of next button action from storyboard** corrected the problem.